# How to provide edit attachment to list but not upload to items

Tags: list, permissions

How to set a group of users who has read permission on SharePoint list can able to edit the attachment, but unable to edit the items and can't able to upload new files in the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without edit item permission level, a sharepoint user wont be able to modify attachments in a list. Not atleast by the web interface.

However, through custom code/solution there is a possibility of doing so through elevated privileges/spcontext tokens ,etc.